# Find the sum of all 2 digit numbers which are formed by the digits 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

There are $7*6=42$ such numbers.

We can index them with $i=1,\dots,42$
and write each of them as $$n_{i}=a_{i}+10b_{i}$$
where $\left\{ a_{i},b_{i}\right\}=\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7\} $

Then $$\sum_{i=1}^{42}n_{i}=\sum_{i=1}^{42}a_{i}+10\sum_{i=1}^{42}b_{i}$$
I can go as far as that

Comment: How could all seven digits be present in a two digit number?

Comment: You're right . There was a mistake in the summary, I changed it

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to approach this problem, but the general approach is to abuse the symmetry of the problem.

Note that for any $i\in S=\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7\}$, there are exactly $7$ numbers that have $i$ as the tens digit, and exactly $7$ with $i$ as the unit digit.

So, your summation is almost right, it isn't a sum from $1\to 42$, but rather, $$7\sum\limits_{i=1}^710\cdot i+7\sum\limits_{i=1}^7i=7\sum\limits_{i=1}^7i+10\cdot i$$$$=7\sum\limits_{i=1}^711i=77\cdot\frac{7\cdot(7+1)}2=\color{red}{2156}$$

Note that if you want numbers with different tens and units digits, one simply needs to multiply the summations by $6$ instead of $7$.

Comment: I don't think repeated digits are allowed.

Comment: @PeterPhipps Other than guessing off of OP's rough work, where did OP specify this?

Comment: In the top line: There are $7*6=42$ such numbers.

Comment: @PeterPhipps I see that, but in the problem itself, OP hasn't specified it. Unless OP changes it, I'm sticking to the answer of the question asked.

Answer (score 1):

From  your use of $42$, I guess you do not want digits to be repeated in a number.

$$\sum_{i=1}^{42}a_{i}=\sum_{i=1}^{42}b_{i}=6(1+2+ ...+7)=168$$

The sum is $11\times 168=1848$.

Comment: While this is correct, it really isn't obvious how you jumped from the two summations to $6(1+2+\hdots+7)$, and then multiplied by $11$. Seems a bit like magic.

Comment: You have six copies of each digit from 1 to 7! Then you have the same sum of the units digits and the 10s digits. I call it maths not magic.

Comment: No I know what you've done here, I'm saying that a random passerby might not.